# Why doesn't my git info show up in my prompt unless I reload my .zshrc?

Tags: git, zsh

As the title says, I have my prompt configured to show my git info. The problem is that it's not showing up unless I reload my zshrc.

```
precmd () {
    if [[ -z  $(git rev-parse --git-dir > /dev/null 2>&1) ]] {
        git_dir=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
        git_split=("${(@s./.)git_dir}")
        git_root=$git_split[-1]
    } else {
        git_root=''
    }

    if [[ -z $(git ls-files --other --exclude-standard 2> /dev/null) ]] {
        zstyle ':vcs_info:*' formats ' [%F{white}%b ${git_root} %c%u%F{green}]'
    } else {
        zstyle ':vcs_info:*' formats ' [%F{white}%b ${git_root} %c%u%F{red}●%F{white}]'
    }

    vcs_info
}
```

I've figured out that this is causing the issue:

```
if [[ -z  $(git rev-parse --git-dir > /dev/null 2>&1) ]] {
    git_dir=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
    git_split=("${(@s./.)git_dir}")
    git_root=$git_split[-1]
} else {
    git_root=''
}
```

but why? How can I solve that? I really want that info in my prompt. It shows what repo I'm in, which is useful when I'm jumping directories a lot. My prompt should look like this:

```
jonathan at  k-nine ~  [master jonathan ●] 10:24 pm
->
```

When it doesn't load it looks like this:

```
jonathan at  k-nine ~  10:26 pm
->
```

Why?

Comment: I do not use zsh but the very first `[[ -z ... ]]` test seems pointless. Documentation suggests that this is the same zero-length-string test as for the `test` command, but `git rev-parse --git-dir` produces output (and exits successfully) if it finds a repository. Redirecting all its output, stdout and stderr both, to `/dev/null` will then *discard* all its output so that the `-z` test always succeeds. What zsh does then if the *next* Git command fails, I don't know.

Comment: I'll try something a little different and see what happens.

Comment: Still looking for an answer